# Iterate over all objects of a class (but not the parents of that class - C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-variables

I want to create a structure where I can "iterate" over all objects of a class (and possibly the objects of all derived classes, though this is ignored then). However it shouldn't iterate over the "parent" classes:

Let's assume I have the following system:

> **A** is the base class
>   **C** and **D** are derived from that
>   **E** is derived from **C**

Now if I would "iterate over D" I would like to iterate over D, but not over a. However in the same I would like to be able to "iterate over C" - this would let me iterate over all "C" objects - and possibly also all E objects (though that isn't necessary, it isn't bad either).

How can I make this happen?

I tried by putting a static variable called "myObjects" which would link all objects.. However I soon noticed that I can't overload static variables in derived classes. (and thus the "myObjects" of C would be the same as the "myObjects" of A, or D)

Comment: Post your class declarations (simplified), and some code illustrating how you'd like to use this & what the expected behavior is

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? To what end (purpose) are you attempting to fulfill? I ask because I really don't understand what you mean by "iterate over `D` but not over `A`". Do you want to iterate over instances of `D`? If so, then you are implicitly iterating over instances of `A` since `D` derives from `A`. Unfortunately I honestly don't understand what your question is. It's likely that there's a better solution to your actual problem, whatever it is.

Comment: The class hierarchy isn't really the relevent bit. What type of container are you using here? You seem to have objects of type A, C, D and E, what structure are you storing them in and how are they generated?

Comment: Hi,  Well What I want to do is in case I have an class called "animals", and subclasses "fish" and "humans". Now I would like to perform some code on all "fishes".. And later perform code on all "humans".. And again sometime also maybe on all "animals". Things such "destruction of that object", or "calculate average weight".

Answer (score 2):

```
int count = std::accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), 0, [](int current_count, A* a)
                           {
                             if (dynamic_cast<D*>(a)) ++current_count;
                             return current_count;
                           });
```

should do the trick.

If you don't have lambda available of course you'll have to put all that in a real function.

count_if version:

```
auto count = std::count_if(x.begin(), x.end(), [](A* a) { return dynamic_cast<D*>(a) != 0; });
```

If you don't have auto then you need to declare the type: `std::iterator_traits<X_type::iterator>::difference_type`

You could just try assigning to `int` but, if I'm reading correctly, `difference_type` can be any integral type and could cause warning/overflow.  Doubtful that would come up and a static_cast will fix it.

If you just want to call some op on D*'s then use foreach and the above methodology to do so.  You might want to review the various Visitor patterns.

Comment: You would use `count_if` here.  `for_each` might be better for what OP wants - this would work if all instances are in single container anyway so +1

Comment: I don't see how for_each would be better at all.  You might chose count_if but you have more control over the type with accumulate.

Comment: OK, reread the OP and they may want for_each.  I'm not going to go over the details specific to that use.  There's sufficient information in the answer to figure it out.  SO dweebs demanding full examples of every basic thing can write it themselves.

Comment: I agree, getting hints (as long as they are adapted to the level of the OP, no always easy to get) is sufficient. Thinking something over makes for a better learning experience that reading it.

Answer (score 0):

> However I soon noticed that I can't overload static variables in derived classes

Of course not, you cannot overload any variables. Overloading only applies to functions, because they can differ in their signatures.

You could have a constructor taking a `bool` in the base class that indicates whether or not the object is to be put into the "list of known objects" and provide `false` as the default. Then only call that constructor with `true` inside the derived class whose objects actually should be inserted into the list.

But there is probably an even better solution that ditches inheritance in favor of policies.

Comment: Here's a hint for you then: Go to bed. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Make an abstract class intermediary between A and it's children.  Put your static object in there.  Then derive classes from that instead of directly from A.  For example:

```
class A {};


 // make this class abstract, or not
class subA : A {
    static std::list<subA *> list_;
};

class C : subA {};
class D : subA {};
```

Comment: That would mean that the list of D contains also objects of type C.

Comment: @paul23: I thought that was what you were asking for, a way to iterate over all the objects of the classes derived from A, but not over objects of type A itself.  I must have misread your post.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this work by each of your classes containing a `static` container of instances of that class that have no subclasses.

Then on construction, each class provides a `protected` constructor for use by subclasses, and a `public` constructor for non-inherited instance creation.  The `protected` constructor in each class does not add `this` to the container of instances, while the `public` constructor adds `this` to the container.

This way the static container in each class contains only those instances of the class that have no subclasses. A virtual function in the base class to access the instance list could be overridden in each subclass to access the class-specific container.

Destruction and copy construction would have to be smart enough to maintain the container correctly as well.

Comment: Problem is how to create that "class specific" container.. Would it involve in typing out the container inside each class again? Or well, would it involve thus finding a new "name" for each subclass?

Comment: Yes, you would need `static container<Class*>` in each class. Otherwise the containers are not per-class. There may be a neater way to do this with an external class template to encapsulate the container but each class must have its own.  One alternative is to keep a single list as suggested by @Noah and act on only the class you need by iterating the entire list and checking each for a match.